# HELP - How do you push / stretch a tessellated mesh like this medical video?

Tags: cloth-simulation, displacement, soft-body

I'm trying to replicate a very cool detail I saw in a medical video, but I just can't figure out how it was done. I tried doing it with a cloth sim or soft body sim, but it just won't work properly.

Is there a way to replicate this precisely or even better?

In the gif you see some red tessellated tissue being push away by the plastic balls, but when the balls shrink the tissue stays in place.

[image]

**[In my file](https://we.tl/t-rQ1t14kAzA)** you can see that the tissue is being pushed backwards but not like the way you see in the video.

[image]

Can someone please show me how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For this effect you can get away with **Cast Modifier** instead of using Cloth simulation.

The [Cast Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/modifiers/deform/cast.html) displaces the vertices of the mesh on a primitive surface like Sphere, Cylinder or Cuboid.

In this case the best primitive to choose as **Shape** from the above is **Cylinder**.

Using **Empty** (pay attention to its orientation bellow) as (Control) **Object** you can control the center of the Cylinder to cast the nearby vertices on.

Turn on **Size From Radius** and **Use Transform** check boxes.
You can get best results when the Empty object is placed inside an empty space.
Play with the **Radius** of the Cylinder and the casting **Factor**.

You can add multiple Cast Modifiers if you need additional "holes".

Animating the Factor value causes the holes to appear expanding.

[image]